# How to display all rows of every group

Tags: php, sql

The problem is every group of column2 are displaying only one item per group. I tried to use an ORDER BY but the column3 clone every row. [Sample Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyimv.png)

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_menu 
            JOIN tbl_cat ON tbl_menu.cat_id = tbl_cat.cat_id 
        GROUP BY cat_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $menu_id = $row['menu_id'];
        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
        $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
        $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3 class="font-weight-light" value="cat_id"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h3>
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="<?php echo $menu_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $menu_name; ?>">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $menu_id; ?>"><?php echo $menu_name; ?></label>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php 
    }
} 
?>
```

Sample Table:

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 |cat_id|  Col3  |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    1 | Orange |
|    2 |    1 | Mango  |
|    3 |    2 | Grapes |
|    4 |    2 | Apple  |
|    5 |    3 | Banana |
+------+------+--------+
```

The output is display only one row every group.
For example: In column2 with ID of 1 it will show only Orange.

Comment: That's how `GROUP BY` works in SQL. If you want to fetch all results and group them in view, you should `ORDER BY cat_name` and figure out the rest in PHP.

Comment: is your code working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is what happens when you run MySQL with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode disabled

Normally a database will complain if you don't mention in a group by any columns that are not in an aggregate function:

```
--throws an error - AddressCity must be present in the group by, or in an aggregate function
SELECT Name, AddressCity, AVG(Age) as AvgAge
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name

--this is ok - we group by the city too
SELECT Name, AddressCity, AVG(Age) as AvgAge
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name, AddressCity

--this is also ok - we get the max city in the select
SELECT Name, MAX(AddressCity), AVG(Age) as AvgAge
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name
```

Aggregate functions are things like MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM, COUNT, STDDEV etc

Your query doesn't fully specify in the GROUP BY, the columns in the SELECT that aren't in an aggregate function. Logically there isn't any good or consistent way to get your query working because you haven't explicitly said what you want the database to do, so MySQL just guesses (it arbitrarily selects a single value to get the query working). You could conceive that it works like this:

```
SELECT Name, CHOOSE_RANDOM(AddressCity), AVG(Age) as AvgAge
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name
```

This means that for data of:

```
Name, AddressCity, Age
John, London, 30
John, Paris, 40
```

It produces either:

```
John, London, 35
```

Or:

```
John, Paris, 35
```

Name `John` is grouped, so the db knows what to do with it. Age is averaged so 35 is the average.. Then MySQL just chooses London or Paris, whatever it feels like (there may be rules to what it selects, but because you aren't saying specifically you can't know for certain)

So what to do about that situation where "I want the average age of all Johns, and a full list of where all the Johns live" ?

You group and average in a sub query and then join this summarized data back to your details:

```
SELECT 
  p.Name, p.AddressCity, summary.AvgAge
FROM
  Person p
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Name, AVG(Age) as AvgAge FROM Person GROUP BY Name) summary
  ON p.Name = summary.Name
```

Oh, and enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY so that MySQL throws an error if you don't correctly fully group/aggregate a query. Running without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is a bit like programming in VB - it lets you play fast and loose, but actually encourages buggy code because it's silently patching up syntax errors, but then it doesn't give you what you want because it's encouraged a way of developing where you're not being precise